# IE6 CSS Float Dropdown Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I'm struggling with an IE6 float issue. (I know IE6 sucks but my huge company uses it..) I've created a simple, header, body, footer layout, with a content area and sidebar within the body. Essentially a common blog layout.

I've had no problem achieving this in IE6 but within the content area I've tried to create a featured area div across the top, then below it two divs side by side. It looks fine in modern browsers but in IE6 it puts the 2nd div below the 1st. Like the divs are too big for the container so it pushes the 2nd. But that shouldn't be the issue since they are both small enough (width, padding, margin) to fit..

And here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="feature">
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="#1">
</div>

<div id="#2">
</div>

</div><!--Content End-->

<div id="sidebar">
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</div><!--Body Content End-->
</div><!--Page Wrap End-->

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#page-wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#header {
    width: 954px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 3px 2px 3px;
    border-bottom: #7E7871 dotted 3px;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 5px 0 15px;
}
#feature {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0;
}
#content #1 {
    border-right: thin solid #CCC;
    width: 305px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
#content #2 {
    width: 305px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../_images/bg_aside.gif) repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: IE6 was just pronounced dead by MS a day ago, they baked a cake: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/01/03/microsoft_ie6_death/

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided much detail as to *how* your HTML/CSS doesn't work in your browser, the only error I can find in your code is you have a stray `</div>`:

```
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="header">
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="feature">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div id="programs">
        </div>

        <div id="discounts">
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    --> </div><!-- THIS ONE! -->

        <div id="sidebar">
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div id="footer">
        </div>

        </div><!-- Body content end -->
    </div><!-- Page wrap end -->
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I added on to my question to be more specific and deleted the extra div. That div was just a typo in the write up.. Thanks JamWaffles.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons it will dip below is due to content being larger than the div.

However, your css does not match the provided HTML.  It's hard to debug some of this without the actual content.

Assuming #2 and #1 are #discounts and #programs, I suggest adding an overflow: scroll; to see how it changes.

Comment: I've corrected the mark-up. Sorry about that. I've given the overflow:scroll a shot. It puts the divs next to each other but there are scroll bars.